# Me muestra un DeprecationWarning al intentar usar cross_validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Actualmente al ejecutar el módulo de CrossValidation y GridSearch, me muestra este error:

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
"This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py:43: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. This module will be removed in 0.20.
DeprecationWarning)
```

¿A qué se debe? y ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es un 'deprecation warning', eso significa que `cross_validation` será eliminado en versiones futuras de la libreria y dejará de tener soporte, concretamente en Scikit-learn v0.20 ya no estará disponible. Es un aviso para que no lo uses por este motivo, si lo usas y  usas tu código con versiones iguales o posteriores a la 0.20 tu script no será válido. En la práctica puedes ignorar este aviso y seguir usando el módulo mientras no actualizes a la versión 0.20.

El propio mensaje te indica que consideres usar en su lugar  el módulo `model_selection` en el cual se supone que habrá métodos sustitutivos de los encontrados en el módulo anterior. Simplemente tienes que cambiar el import adecuadamente, solo como ejemplo :

```
 from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

por:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Te dejo el [enlace](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection) a la documentación oficial donde viene detallado el contenido del módulo `model_selection`, aquí puedes ver las funciones y clases que contiene.